# How to express that a variable can only take a limited number of values?

Tags: python

I am trying to find a way to constrain a variable value in python.
For example, let's say that I have a variable door that can only take two values: open or closed. Something like

```
door = 'open' || 'closed'
```

Then when I use door somewhere, I am confident I don't need to check the values, asserting that door is nothing else than open or closed.

Maybe with a class?

```
class Door(object):
   open = 'open'
   closed = 'closed'

   def value(v=True, self):
      if v return open else return closed
```

But then what to do if the variable can take more than two values (I am saved by the very nature of a boolean here)?
How would you do it?

Comment: Sounds like you wnt an enum? https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Comment: Your use of `Door(object)` makes me think you're still on Python 2? `enum` was added in Python 3.4.

Comment: Yes, still on python 2 unfortunately. That will change soon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider using `enum`:

```
import enum

class Door(enum.Enum):
    open = 'open'
    closed = 'closed'

d = Door('open')
print(d.value)
d = Door('closed')
print(d.value)
d = Door('is not a valid Door')
print(d.value)
```

Output:

```
open
closed
ValueError: 'is not a valid Door' is not a valid Door
```

Comment: You type faster than I do. The only things I'd add are a [link to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#module-enum) and a mention that there's no way to really restrict the value a variable can take. There's nothing stopping `d = 'foo'`, for example. That's the nature of dynamically-typed languages.

Comment: Even with an enum, nothing actually prevents you from assigning `d = 'doorknob'` instead of an enum constant, though. You still have to make sure you don't assign anything but the valid values to your variable, and you could have done that without the enum.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. That's right, you can't exactly constrain the nature of the variable, but that will be good enough. My docstrings will tell me if the variable type is Door or something else.

Comment: Is enum only in python 3?

Comment: @Barnabe only starting from 3.4

Comment: Oh I see it's been back ported. That's fine, thanks.

Comment: Yes, with [enum34](https://pypi.org/project/enum34/) this code works in python2.7 as in python3.4+.